# How to execute somethnig `finally` in Javascript swich-case statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

In javascript `switch` statements, I would like to execute some function if any one of the `case` is satisified:

```
switch (myVar){
  case 0:
    do_something_0();
    break;
  case 1:
    do_something_1();
    break;
  // I want to execute myFunc() if myVar === 1 or myVar === 2
}
```

I came up with the idea of having auxiliary variable `haveMatched`, like this.

```
var haveMatched=false;
switch (myVar){
  case 0:
    do_something_0();
    haveMatched=true;
    break;
  case 1:
    do_something_1();
    haveMatched=true;
    break;
}
if (haveMatched){
  do_finally();
}
```

I think there might be better way of achieving this (for example, I would've tried the similar way if I hadn't known about the `default:` keyword). Am I doing it right, or am I missing something?

Comment: Just put the put it inside each `case`.

Comment: I thought writing exactly the same line multiple times should be avoided if possible. Especially in this case, what I want to achieve is not "Do this for case 0, 1, ..." but "Do this for any of the cases written above". Even if those two result in the same outcome, I feel the former, putting it inside each case, is less readable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you rewrite your code to include a default case you don't have to include `haveMatched = true` in every case.

```
var haveMatched=true;
switch (myVar){
  case 0:
    do_something_0();
    break;
  case 1:
    do_something_1();
    break;
  default:
    haveMatched = false;
}
if (haveMatched){
  do_finally();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the function in the case:

```
switch (myVar){
  case 0:
    do_something_0();
    do_finally();
    break;
  case 1:
    do_something_1();
    do_finally();
    break;
}
```

Comment: first, OP isn't asking for alternatives, but a direct solution. second, replicating function calls is a recipe for "off-by-one" bugs

Answer (score 1):

Include the function in every case block, you don't need a flag...

```
switch (myVar){
  case 0:
    do_something_0();
    do_finally();
    break;
  case 1:
    do_something_1();
    do_finally();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a workaround:

```
  try {
    switch (option) {
        case 0:
            console.log("option 0");
            break;
        case 1:
            console.log("option 1");
            break;
        default:

    }
} catch (err) {
    throw err;
} finally {
    doActionFinally();
}
```

Comment: Not a recommended one, JavaScript suspends the control flow statements of try and catch blocks until the execution of the finally block finishes. So, when return, throw, break, or continue is used in finally. Please read here: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unsafe-finally